# Full Email Address is not Showing in @Email Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a page for registration where i am saving details of users.

Page is working fine data is shaving but 'full email address' is not showing in table of  '@email' column.

**Example:** if i am saving 'cozm02011@gmail.com' it is showing only 'cozm02011' in table.

[image]

**code behind**

```
 protected void ceratenewuser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "User_pro";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox3.Text.Trim());

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastSeen", DateTime.Now);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now);


        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            Label2.Text = "User Created successfully";

            TextBox1.Text = ""; TextBox2.Text = ""; TextBox3.Text = ""; TextBox4 .Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }


        this.GridView1.DataBind();


    }
```

**store procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.User_pro
@UserName varchar(20),
@Password varchar(20),
@Email varchar(50),
@LastSeen datetime,
@CreatedDate datetime

AS      

INSERT INTO User_tbl (UserName, Password, Email, LastSeen, CreatedDate)
VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @Email, @LastSeen, @CreatedDate)
RETURN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the "**Confirm password**" field to the E-mail column

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
```

TextBox3 is used for "Confirm password" field.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: thanks.................TextBox3 is being used for confirm password but  i was using it for email.